# Solidity Oraclize error

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles

I am learning to use oracles in solidity and I have taken this code to see how it works. But I get the following error: "VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. "

If someone knows how to help me I appreciate it, I've been trying for several days to make it work but I can not.

Thank you

The code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./oraclize.sol";

contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {

uint public DieselPriceUSD;

event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
event newDieselPrice(string price);

function DieselPrice() public payable{
    update(); // first check at contract creation
}

function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result)public {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
    newDieselPrice(result);
    DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
    // do something with the USD Diesel price
}

function update() payable {
    newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
    oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it, the problem is that I was using the JavaScript VM and had to use web3